# Android: Any way to remove AM/PM in TextClock?

Tags: android, xml, clock

I am currently using TextClock in my xml, however I do not want the AM/PM to be in the displayed time. Is there a way to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html#setFormat12Hour(java.lang.CharSequence)) you could use the following:

```
setFormat12Hour( "K:m" );
```